# Is NSMutableArray an ordered collection of objects in Contiguous Memory Allocation?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

Have a basic Objective-C data structure question wrt NSMutableArray which I was asked in an interview.

I know that NSArray is an ordered collection of objects stored in contiguous memory location. This might be possible as the array size is fixed at the time of creation of the array object, so the OS allocates the contiguous memory accordingly.

What about NSMutableArray. Is it also ordered and contiguous? The reason I ask is that at run time, we could add n-number of objects to the mutable array and the mutable array could grow to a large size. Beyond a point, it might not be possible for the objects to be stored in contiguous memory location.

Comment: The answers will be pure speculation (unless an Apple engineer chimes in), and are completely irrelevant, as the implementation may change.

Comment: You don't need to be an Apple engineer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Both are not ordered collections of objects, they are ordered collections of object *references*.

NSMutableArray is capable of inserting and deleting elements at or near both the beginning and the end of the array quickly. That's what you need to know. You should easily figure out a data structure that achieves this.

Since NSArray and NSMutableArray store *references*: It would be unusual that an array of *references* grows so large that it causes problems, because the objects themselves would cause problems first. And if you run out of memory, iOS will just kill your app and you reduce the amount of memory that it needs.

Comment: you are right. Found below mentioned statement in the book _iOS Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th Edition_ **"In Objective-C, an array does not contain the objects that belong to it; instead it holds a pointer to each object. When an object is added to an array, the address of that object in memory is stored inside the array."**